# Iterating through a list to then return a value if meeting conditions

Tags: python, pandas, list

I just started working with Pandas for a personal side project of mine. I've imported data from a CSV, cleaned it up and now want to use data from the CSV in the rest of my code. I want to ask a user for input and if the user input matches an entry inside the list (Which is a column inside the data) I want to get data for that instance (from the same row but other columns in the df)

I can get it to compare using the "in" statement but don't think that will work when I expand the functionality.

How would I go about looping through the list from the df to return a value from that list if it exists and then be able to return other values in the same row of the df?

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import math

housing_Data = pd.read_csv("/Users/saads/Downloads/DP_LIVE_26072020053911478.csv") #File to get data
housing_Data = housing_Data.drop(['INDICATOR', 'MEASURE', 'FREQUENCY', 'Flag Codes'], axis=1) #Removing unwanted Columns
print(housing_Data.columns) # Just to test if working
user_Country = str(input("What Country are you in")) # User Input

def getCountry(): # Function to compare user input to elements inside the list
    if user_Country in housing_Data.LOCATION.unique():
        print(user_Country)
    else:
        print("Sorry we don't have information about that country")


getCountry()
```

Comment: its not clear what your asking for, to me at least.

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you want is all rows matching a location?

```
matching_rows = housing_Data[housing_Data.LOCATION == user_country]
print(matching_rows)
```

maybe? Im not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are urgent , you can append the iteration list from the source to a newfile.txt and do a comfortable iteration. hopefully it helps.